# Changing conf in nginx for react router

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

My react app has following routes

1. localhost
2. localhost/ca/:num
3. localhost/cr/:num

All three are working fine in localhost

When I use nginx localhost only works. sub paths `/ca` `/cr` are not working. I have changed the conf file as below

```
location / {
  root   html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

How to run these paths and get the dynamic :num value as well

Comment: Any errors in nginx logs?

Comment: I forgot to reload nginx. It's solved